# Передача параметров в фрагмент НЕ через setArguments()

Tags: android, android-fragment

На сколько мне известно, для передачи параметров фрагменту принято использовать bundle и setArguments(), доставая их в onCreate() фрагмента. Беда в том, что сложные объекты так передавать муторно (сериализация и т.д.). Хотелось бы узнать чем плох предлагаемый способ передачи - могут ли возникнуть какие-то неприятные последствия при определённых условиях?

```
        public static SomeFragment newInstance(SomeObject so) {
        SomeFragment fragment = new SomeFragment();
        fragment.mSomeObject = so;
        return fragment;
    }
```

Вроде как не воспрещается доставать фрагменты из fragmentManager и вызывать у них различные функции. А вот так вот, до того, как фрагмент начал свой жизненный цикл - задать ему внутренние поля при создании? Это нормальная практика, или так лучше не делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы перевернете экран, ваш объект разрушится вместе с фрагментом, агрументы в свою очередь автоматически сетятся во фрагмент при перевороте.